# VS2010 Build Error at PuTTY Source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, build, putty

i'm download putty source code from website.

and open putty.dsw file.

VS2010 auto convert that project files.

finally. just build only putty.

but i got this message.

```
Error   27  error C1189: #error :   You must define one of SECURITY_WIN32, SECURITY_KERNEL, or  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\sspi.h  60  1   putty
Error   35  error C1189: #error :   You must define one of SECURITY_WIN32, SECURITY_KERNEL, or  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\sspi.h  60  1   putty
```

Preprocessor Definitions

```
WIN32
_DEBUG
_WINDOWS
```

and Not Using Precompiled Headers.

i googled. so i found putty build from cygwin.

but just wondering about how to build putty at vs2010.

Comment: Did you try to define SECURITY_WIN32 or SECURITY_KERNEL ?

Comment: Add "putty.h"

`#define SECURITY_WIN32
#define SECURITY_KERNEL`

and build.
but. i got more error message ;-(

`Error 23 error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'ServiceClass' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\sspi.h 1854 1 putty
Error 24 error C2061: syntax error : identifier`

i don't know why that happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as Matthias said above, you need to add a line like

```
#define SECURITY_WIN32
```

to the putty.h file. Don't add/define `SECURITY_KERNEL` that's what caused additional errors.